# Ionic splash screen doesn't work

Tags: ionic-framework, screen, splash-screen

I'm trying to show splash screen for my app in Ionic. I've read many articles and tutorials and still nothing... Will it work via browser or only on device? I tried both ways and still no splash screen. Help me guys, I don't know what am I doing wrong. Here is my code:

[config.xml]

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000"/>
<platform name="android">
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
<splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
<icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" height="2048"/>
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" height="2732"/>
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
</platform>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
```

[app.js]

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if (window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
navigator.splashscreen.show();
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The splashscreen will only work on a device.

Check you have installed this cordova plugin: `cordova-plugin-splashscreen`.
You can check it with `cordova plugin list` command.

You don't have anything more to do.

If it's still not working, I suggest to add your splashscreen again with `ionic resources --splash` command. See [Ionic doc about splashscreens](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html).

Comment: It's weird. Did you try on a clean project? Do you have a blank screen instead of the splashscreen or something else?

Comment: I did not try on clean project. Today I will test that. I have no splash screen, even blank one.

Answer (score 0):

This question was also answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41896430/3560939

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41896430/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)